# Why can't I specify the type of the names, in a named tuple, as a tuple of symbols in Julia?

Tags: syntax-error, runtime-error, julia

There's this function:

```
function Γ(state::Dict{Symbol, <:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}})::Vector{NamedTuple{<:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}, <:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}}}
    kwargs = Dict(kwargs)
    keys = [key for (key, value) ∈ state]
    instances_vec = [value for (key, value) ∈ state]
    data = Vector{Vector{Symbol}}()
    function recursive(data, current, depth = 1)
        if depth <= length(instances_vec)
            for instance ∈ instances_vec[depth]
                recursive(data, push!(copy(current), instance), depth + 1)
            end
        else
            push!(data, current)
        end
    end
    recursive(data, [])
    return [(;zip(keys,configuration)...) for configuration ∈ data]
end
```

which when run like this:

```
identifiers = Dict(:Id=>(:One, :Two, :Three, :Four, :Five), :Nationality=>(:Brit, :German), :Color=>(:Red, :Blue, :Green))

Γ(identifiers)
```

gives the following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type
NamedTuple{(:Id, :Nationality, :Color),Tuple{Symbol,Symbol,Symbol}} to an object of type
NamedTuple{#s589,#s588} where #s588<:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol,N} where N} where #s589<:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol,N} where N}
```

The type of the returned is: `Array{NamedTuple{(:Id, :Nationality, :Color),Tuple{Symbol,Symbol,Symbol}},1}`
and the type of `(:Id, :Nationality, :Color)` is `Tuple{Symbol,Symbol,Symbol}`
so I don't see why this gives a conversion error when there is no need for conversion especially since:

```
typeof((:Id, :Nationality, :Color)) <: Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}} && Tuple{Symbol,Symbol,Symbol} <: Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}} = true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the conversion comes from the fact that the declaration of your function
declares a return type. If you remove (or comment out) this type annotation

```
function Γ(state::Dict{Symbol, <:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}}) #::Vector{NamedTuple{<:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}, <:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}}}
    kwargs = Dict() # <- there was a typo here in your minimal example
    keys = [key for (key, value) ∈ state]
    instances_vec = [value for (key, value) ∈ state]
    data = Vector{Vector{Symbol}}()
    function recursive(data, current, depth = 1)
        if depth <= length(instances_vec)
            for instance ∈ instances_vec[depth]
                recursive(data, push!(copy(current), instance), depth + 1)
            end
        else
            push!(data, current)
        end
    end
    recursive(data, [])
    return [(;zip(keys,configuration)...) for configuration ∈ data]
end
```

then everything is fine:

```
julia> identifiers = Dict(:Id=>(:One, :Two, :Three, :Four, :Five), :Nationality=>(:Brit, :German), :Color=>(:Red, :Blue, :Green))
Dict{Symbol,Tuple{Symbol,Symbol,Vararg{Symbol,N} where N}} with 3 entries:
  :Id          => (:One, :Two, :Three, :Four, :Five)
  :Nationality => (:Brit, :German)
  :Color       => (:Red, :Blue, :Green)

julia> Γ(identifiers)
30-element Array{NamedTuple{(:Id, :Nationality, :Color),Tuple{Symbol,Symbol,Symbol}},1}:
 (Id = :One, Nationality = :Brit, Color = :Red)
 (Id = :One, Nationality = :Brit, Color = :Blue)
 (Id = :One, Nationality = :Brit, Color = :Green)
 [...]
```

Note that typing the arguments of a function/method where necessary is considered good practice. However, code that provides type assertions for return values is often less idiomatic in Julia: the compiler is really good at figuring out what the return type is!

Now the reason why this conversion fails is because the element type provided in
the signature is not consistent with the actual element type of the returned
vector:

```
julia> elem = (Id = :One, Nationality = :Brit, Color = :Red)
(Id = :One, Nationality = :Brit, Color = :Red)

julia> typeof(elem)
NamedTuple{(:Id, :Nationality, :Color),Tuple{Symbol,Symbol,Symbol}}

julia> elem isa NamedTuple{<:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}, <:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}}
false
```

For `NamedTuple{A,B}` to match `NamedTuple{<:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}},
<:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}}`, both conditions below have to hold:

- `A <: Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}`
- `B <: Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}`

Here, we have:

```
A = (:Id, :Nationality, :Color)
B = Tuple{Symbol,Symbol,Symbol}
```

so that, like you said, the condition for `B` holds:

```
julia> B <: Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}
true
```

but not the condition for `A`:

```
julia> A <: Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}
ERROR: TypeError: in <:, expected Type, got Tuple{Symbol,Symbol,Symbol}
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[10]:1

       # A is a value of type Tuple{...}, not the type itself
julia> typeof(A) <: Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}
true
```

Comment: I see. so the first parameter of NamedTuple isn't a type but a value, right? In that case what signature for the return type suffices? Thanks a lot for the valuable information!

Comment: Maybe something like this: `Vector{NamedTuple{T, <:Tuple{Vararg{Symbol}}} where T}`. But, unless you have a compelling reason to do so, I would advise not to type the return value of your function.